# In MFC how to select multiple items in the Combo-box?

Tags: mfc

In MFC dialog based application, I have a combo box. Is it possible to select multiple items in the Combo-box through mouse and keyboard operations and also by pro-grammatically?

```
m_ctrlComboBox.AddString("Type1");
m_ctrlComboBox.AddString("Type2");
m_ctrlComboBox.AddString("Type3");
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: No you can't do this, neither per user interaction nor programatically. Anyway, selecting multiple items in a combo box doesn't make much sense from the user's perspective. You probably are better of using a listbox instead of a combo box.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/about-combo-boxes):

> A combo box consists of a list and a selection field. The list presents the options that a user can select, and the selection field displays the current selection. If the selection field is an edit control, the user can enter information not available in the list; otherwise, the user can only select items in the list.

The selection field is only capable of displaying a single selected item (at most). There is no way to allow a user (or code) to select multiple items at the same time. This is immediately obvious when looking at the [CB_GETCURSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cb-getcursel) and [CB_SETCURSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cb-setcursel) messages, that only allow for a single index to be passed.

A [list view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bumper-list-view-list-view-control-overviews) control allows multiple items to be selected at the same time.

Comment: A list box (CListBox) also allows multiple items to be selected.

Comment: @jab: A [list box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/about-list-boxes) is just a stripped down version of a list view.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wanted to point out that the OP probably wants a list box rather than a combo box. The upvote is mine btw.